# Flash as3 - Movieclip using a Timer to update dynamic text. No update

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am new to as3.
I am trying to create a very simple **countdown** using `Timer` class.

1. I've got a `movieclip`, which has got a `dynamic text` element.
2. The `movieclip` uses a package for its code
3. The package if obviously derived from the MovieClip class
4. I've got a `timer`, that updates the dynamic text field every second.

When debugging the code, I see that the timer works well. Its updates the value of the dynamic text field.

However, from some reason it the ui itself doesn't get updated. What am I missing here?

Comment: could u please paste some piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

If your timer is "working" (meaning you can trace it and see that it's printing values out to the log as expected) then it's most likely a problem with the way you've set the font in the text field.
If you're sure the text field's instance name is being invoked correctly (trace out the object to be sure Flash is aware of it, as in... trace( myTextField);// (this should not be null, or undefined, provided you've set the instance name of your text field to 'myTextField'.

If thisis all correct, then it's almost certainly font embedding issues. This is where CS4> have really screwed the pooch. Click on the text field and select a font and then click embed fonts. After you've embeded the font and given it some name of your own ("myArialBold") you'll THEN need to find *myArialBold in the list of available fonts (in the properties pane, not in the fonts dialogue) and select your embedded font.

It doesn't make any rational sense, since you *feel like you've selected the font when you were in the embed dialog, but in fact, that's just where you embed the font into the environment, it doesn't actually take effect on this particular text field till you've selected it from the drop down of all your fonts (where it will now also be, towards the top, above a line where all your own custom embedded fonts dwell).

The upside is that it will now be there for the duration of this project and you can just select it for any text field (and not need to embed it again).

the down side is that if you ever delete the embed but forget to change the association on ANY text field, Flash will complain every time you open this project that a font that's being sought is missing and you will rip out every last hair on your head looking for where this text field is. In a large project, I've seen this lead to people killing themselves. Very sad.

If that doesn't work, we'll need to see more of your code :)

Comment: screwed the pooch. hahaha.. but this is a HUMONGOUS gotcha that took me 10 hours to figure out, glad I'm not the only one :D

Comment: Yeah... I lost a similar amount of time as I stumbled across this, seemingly as soon as i downloaded the update. No one had ever seen this font mechanism then.... it was agony.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much more to it than this basic test... other problems may have to do with text formatting but as far as the Timer is concerned it doesn't really go beyond this.

If you're new to AS3 , try to break down your application into smaller chunks to find out where it breaks...

```
private var textfield:TextField = new TextField();
private var increment:int;
private var timer:Timer = new Timer( 1000 );

private function init():void
{
    addChild( textfield );

    timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER , updateText );
    timer.start();  
}

private function updateText( event:TimerEvent):void
{
    increment++;
    textfield.text = increment.toString();  
}
```

Comment: Note that as this as written, you don't have a reference to your timer, so at some point it will likely get garbage collected, causing your timer to stop working mysteriously.

Comment: Agreed... this would do for a quick test though. Editing the answer!